# How to make users in different Thread groups work one after the other

Tags: jmeter

I am inexperienced in jmeter. I had a Test plan of three thread groups and multiple HTTP requests in them
Thread Group 1 (10 threads)

HTTP request (log in)

HTTP request (add a file)

HTTP request (open file)

HTTP request (sign out)

Thread Group 1(15 threads)

HTTP request (log in)

HTTP request (add a file)

HTTP request (open file)

HTTP request (sign out)

Thread Group 1 (25 threads)

HTTP request (log in)

HTTP request (add a file)

HTTP request (open file)

HTTP request (sign out)

Now I need to make first 10 users log in and add files and after that next 15 users should log in and add file, while first 10 users opening a file next 25 users should log in and 15 users should add a file same for open a file and users should log out one after the another.

Answer (score 0):

Enable this checkbox `Run Therad Groups consecutively`.

[image]